# Using mvcContrib with nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mvccontrib

can we use MvcContrub grid with NHibernate as used with linq in following tutorial and how?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Grid_Paging_In_MVC3.aspx?display=Normal&fid=1616049&df=90&mpp=10&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=None&select=3828479&fr=9

Comment: i think this should work     IQueryable<User> o = session.CreateQuery("").List<User>().AsQueryable();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can, but i it's better to use QueryOver than NHibernate Linq provider.
(QueryOver is more complex, but flexible)
Look at:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx

http://www.philliphaydon.com/tag/queryover/